# Set a specific port for javaw.exe and java.exe

Tags: firewall, java, port

I understood the differences between `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` by this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/35116/what-is-the-difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe/852394#852394).

I know that `javaw.exe` and `java.exe` belongs to Java from Sun Microsystems (Run time library), they have some dynamic ports in my server for example 49203, 49204, 49209, 49210 and so on.

I'd like to set a specific port for `javaw.exe` and `jave.exe` because of firewall policy. How can I do it?

**Update:**

I'd like to permit used ports and deny the others by switch `ACL`(Access Control List), For example:

> switch(conf)>ip access-list extended Firewall
>   switch(conf-ipacc)>permit tcp any(source-ip) any(source-port) 192.168.5.10(server-ip) 53(server-local-port) priority 10
>   switch(conf-ipacc)>permit tcp any any 192.168.5.10 49158 priority 50
>   .
>   .
>   switch(conf-ipacc)>deny tcp any any 192.168.5.10 any priority 1000

Comment: That would depend on the firewall you are using. If the ports are opened by java or a different application is rather irrelevant.

Comment: I used the `ACL` on switch to allow or block specific port. For more clarification I updated my post.